# How would I preface being on the president's list in the same way that someone can be a “winner” of an award, on a bullet list

Tags: funding, cv, writing-style

(Referred here from English SE)

I'm trying to write a bullet list of accomplishments for a scholarship renewal, and I'd like to include that I am on the University President's list.

Typically in a bullet list of such things, you (and this is extremely difficult to phrase) "preface" each item with a word, such as "Winner of x award", or "member of x club." (Where "winner" and "member" are the words in question.)

Seeing as the Presidents list is neither an award nor an organization per se, how would I preface such an accomplishment?

Answer (score 3):

I would typically term inclusion in such a list an "honor," as in "Awards and Honors."  If you want a verb, however, I would not use "honored" but simply "included", however, as in:

> - Included on University President's List, Miskatonic University

Comment: This fits the bill, thanks! It is appropriate without drawing unnecessary attention or causing awkwardness.